# Will this propagated mulberry straighten out?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, mulberry

I've successfully propagated a mulberry through a [hardwood](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/31496/do-mulberry-hardwood-cuttings-breaking-buds-enjoy-light) cutting.

Now that my worries of it surviving winter have passed (I can see green buds slowly opening), my next challenge is to eventually prune it in to a half standard tree. However the tree thus far kind of zigzags. The leader looks more like a side branch.

My question:
Will this be allright, will it kind of straighten (it does not have to be completely straight)? Or do I have to be on the lookout or even encourage a new leader?

[image: fullsize]
[image: mediumzoom]
[image: zoom]
[image: fullzoom]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will straighten out. If the trunk becomes twice as thick as now, it will still look a little bit curved (not as much as now), but nothing to worry about. It will of course never be as straight as the bamboo stick next to it, but that is not really necessary, is it?